# Two tests in Angular NGTEST, fail 303 and 304

Tags: angular

I'm running the ngtest for my Angular application and I receive two errors related to a new component.

The app works just fine when I serve it but it fails during testing.

> ERROR: 'NG0304: 'app-detail' is not a known element:

> 1. If 'app-detail' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'app-detail' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'

> ERROR: 'NG0303: Can't bind to 'myProperty' since it isn't a known property of 'app-detail'.'

I tried to import the components inside app.module.ts and declare it but it doesn't change anything.

```
   @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppMainComponent,
    AppDetailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    
  ],
  exports: [
    AppComponent,
    AppMainComponent,
    AppDetailComponent
  ],
```

Project outline and how I assume the test fails.

- App
- app.module.ts
- - App-main

NG0304: 'app-main' is not a known element:

- - App-detail

> 'NG0304: 'app-detail' is not a known element:
> 'NG0303: Can't bind to 'myProperty' since it isn't a known property of 'app-detail'.'

Answer (score 3):

This link solved it for me.

I had to add CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA to all my .spec.ts files.

https://akhromieiev.com/is-not-a-known-element-angular-test/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `AppDetailComponent` into the `declarations` and `exports` of your NgModule:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppDetailComponent ],
  exports: [ AppDetailComponent ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

And from your `AppModule` add it into your `imports`:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [ SharedModule ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**If you DONT have a SharedModule**

Just make sure `AppDetailComponent` is within the `declarations` of the `AppModule`:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppDetailComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did not have an exports as part of my app module. I've updated the original post with the app outline. Unfortunally it didnt work when I applied it in the exports.